# Django Form Adding New Database Entries Erroneously

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

Disclaimer: Relatively new to Djano so forgive any shortcomings in the question.

I have a simple form  with a DAL field and I'm trying to submit the form value id and slug to render detail page. DAL is providing results as expected. When submitted, I get the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'asset_detail' with arguments '(39526, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

Note that the ids of existing data stop at 39499. That id (and 39500-39525) was generated upon submission. I don't want to add new entries to the database, but rather look up existing ones. See below for urls, form, views, model, and template:

```
# models.py
class CI(models.Model):
    ci_type = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                related_name='assets',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    asset_tag = models.CharField(max_length=53, blank=True)
    model_source = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=58, blank=True)
    support_level = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lookup:asset_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])

# forms.py
class AssetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),)
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=CI.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='asset-autocomplete',
            forward=(forward.Field('category', 'ci_type'),)))

    class Meta:
        model = CI
        fields = ('name',)

# views.py
class AssetView(CreateView):
    model = CI
    form_class = AssetForm
    template_name = 'lookup/asset.html'

# urls.py
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.ci_detail,
         name='asset_detail'),

#asset.html (template)
  <form action="{{ ci.get_absolute_url }}" method="post">
    <label for="asset_type">Select Asset:</label>
    {% csrf_token %}   
    {{ form.as_p }}
  <div class="col-4">
    <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Select"></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see the error that the slug is `''` (empty string) for the object id `39526`. Did you try changing the slug to non-empty string?

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja The issue that I'm encountering is that when the form is submitted, a whole new entry is being created in the DB, which has no values other than it's assigned ID, the name from the name filed, and a couple of the other default values. for example, if  selected value of `pcl-05-sw01`, with an id of `12345`, What I get is the above error and a new DB entry with the next available ID,`39526` above, and a mirrored name value, `pcl-05-sw01` in this example. This new entry is not the desired result. Also the new entry has no slug value which explains the error.

Comment: It seems that your view extends from `CreateView`, which creates objects, not updates them.

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja Thanks for the keen eye! I've been struggling with this issue for quite some time.

Comment: I hope this wasn't sarcasm :P

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja 100% genuine. You've helped me get past a rather annoying obstacle. Cheers!

Comment: You need to paste the whole traceback, the source of the error is there.